# Diffrence between find and where when fire update event in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When i tried to use Eloquent event (update) it works fine to me , but i noticed that event doesn't fired when i wrote this query

```
Samples::where('id', $id)->update($inputs);
```

but it works when i wrote this

```
Samples::find($id)->update($inputs);
```

and this is my update event

```
  public static function boot()
    {
        static::updating(function ($model) {
          dd('it works !');
        parent::boot();
    }
```

Comment: That is because the events are only fired when you are updating the model, not when you are updating directly on the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first code will directly generate an `UPDATE` query and send it to the database. It will never load any model.

The second code will first execute a `SELECT` query to fill a model and then it will do an `UPDATE` query using the received data.

This is why the first query will never fire your update event.